# "stdin isn't a terminal" with helm-projectile?

Tags: helm, projectile, helm-projectile

Opening up `helm-projectile-find-file` keeps showing me this error:

[screenshot http://zc.d.pr/16fh0/1Ryb9GGB+](http://zc.d.pr/16fh0/1Ryb9GGB+)

Anyone know how to get rid of this? Or what's causing it?

Emacs config here: https://github.com/neezer/.emacs.d/blob/master/config.org